# Flutter and BoxShapeBorder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to add the **"Protection Icon"** on top of the **"Box Shape" border** and make sure that when it moves, it's within Its borderlines on each screen size:

Code:

```dart
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: const Color(0xff182341),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xff5F687E)),
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        
                ),
            ),
          Stack( // Using stack here because of other elements that will be added.
            children: [
          AnimatedPositioned(
                        top: 280,
                        left: 130,
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                        child: Container(
                          child: Image(image: AssetImage('images/g8.png')),
                        ),
                      ),
               ] 
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
```

**Result:**

[image: Screenshot]

However, I only got the iPhone 13 Pro's screen right, the other's aren't where they should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `Positioned` to specify an absolute offset, instead try to use widgets that allow you to set a relative offset (like a percentage), so they will scale well with different screen sizes.

For example, you can replace your `Positioned` for `Align`, like this:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment(-0.75, 0.48), // play around with these values
  child: ...
)
```

The two arguments for `Alignment` class are used to set a percentage offset on `x` and `y` axis, each ranging from `-1.0` to `+1.0`, with `0.0` being the center.